# Unable to fetch response using subscribe in Angular

Tags: c#, angular, typescript

I am trying to get response and assign that to a variable in the subscribe method and later use that variable to retrieve and use the data fetched. Below is my code:

API:

```
public IHttpActionResult GetData(string empID)
{
    empID = empID ?? " ";

    try
    {
        using (var connection = new OracleConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Database"].ConnectionString))
        {
            IRepository repository = new RepositoryClass(connection);
            DataCollection employee = new DataCollection();

            employee.employeeData = repository.GetData(empID).ToList();
            employee.CountInResponse = employee.employeeData.Count;

            if (employee.employeeData != null && employee.CountInResponse > 0) {
                return Ok (employee) 
            }
            else
                return Content(HttpStatusCode.NotFound, "No Employee data found for this request");
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        return CreateLevel3Exception(ex);
    }
}
```

Component:

```
UpdateEmployee()
{
    this.getEmployeeData()

    if(
        this.EmployeeOrigData.EmployeeID == this.newID
        && this.EmployeeOrigData.EmployeeName == this.newName
        && this.EmployeeOrigData.EmployeeContact == this.newContact
        && this.EmployeeOrigData.EmployeeStatus == this.newStatus
        && this.EmployeeOrigData.EmployeeAddress == this.newAdress
    )
    {
        this.Message('info', 'Update invalid');
    }
}


getEmployeeData() {
    this.service.GetEmployeeData(this.addEmployeeID)
        .subscribe((response) => 
        {
            this.EmployeeOrigData = response;
        },
        (err) => 
        {
            if (err == '404 - Not Found')
              this.Message('info', err, 'Update Unsuccessful - Server error');
            else
              this.Message('error', 'Error', err);
        });
}
```

Service:

```
GetEmployeeData(empID: string) {
    debugger;
    let params = new URLSearchParams();
    params.set('empID',empID)
    debugger;
    return this.http.get(Url, { params: params })
          .map(res => res.json().employeeData)
          .catch(this.handleError);
}
```

Here I need to fetch the details based on the Employee ID. I am getting the expected response in the API but after that, inside the subscribe method I am not able to assign it to the variable EmployeeOrigData. What could be wrong?

Comment: `.map(res => res.employeeData)` instead of `.map(res => res.json().employeeData)`. The `HttpClient` will parse the json for you by default.

Comment: @Igor if I try this, then I get the error that Property 'employeeData' does not exist on type 'Response'.

Comment: Are you using the [HttpClientModule](https://angular.io/guide/http) or the obsolete [HttpModule](https://angular.io/guide/deprecations#angularhttp)?

Comment: @Igor HttpModule :_(

Comment: You should upgrade to `HttpClientModule` or add it and start using that anywhere you are refactoring or adding new code.

Answer (score 1):

This answer is applicable to [HttpClientModule](https://angular.io/guide/http).

- In your service use `.map(res => res.employeeData)` instead of `.map(res => res.json().employeeData)`. The `HttpClient` will parse the json for you by default.
- Use the [Pipeable Operators](https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/doc/pipeable-operators.md) instead of the "patch operators".
- Declare return types on your methods and make use of type safety

```
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { map, catchError } from 'rxjs/operators';

//....

GetEmployeeData(empID: string) : Observable<EmployeeData> {
    let params = new URLSearchParams();
    params.set('empID',empID);

    return this.http.get<{employeeData: EmployeeData}>(Url, { params: params })
      .pipe(map(res => res.employeeData)
        , catchError(this.handleError));
}
```

```
export interface EmployeeData {
  // members here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If the http in your service is a httpClient then you don't need to use res.json(), httpclient.get() automatically does that for you

```
 GetEmployeeData(empID: string) {
      let params = new URLSearchParams();
      params.set('empID',empID)
      return this.http.get(Url, { params: params })
          .map(res => res.employeeData)
          .catch(this.handleError);
  }
```

Comment: Property 'employeeData' does not exist on type 'Response', this is what I get on changing the code to this

Answer (score 0):

Make changes to your subscription as follows

```
    this.service.GetEmployeeData(this.addEmployeeID)
            .subscribe((response) => 
            {
                this.EmployeeOrigData = response;
            },
            (err) => 
            {
                if (err == '404 - Not Found')
                  this.Message('info', err, 'Update Unsuccessful - Server error');
                else
                  this.Message('error', 'Error', err);
            },
() => {
if(
        this.EmployeeOrigData.EmployeeID == this.newID
        && this.EmployeeOrigData.EmployeeName == this.newName
        && this.EmployeeOrigData.EmployeeContact == this.newContact
        && this.EmployeeOrigData.EmployeeStatus == this.newStatus
        && this.EmployeeOrigData.EmployeeAddress == this.newAdress
    )
    {
        this.Message('info', 'Update invalid');
    }};
```

and inside UpdateEmployee() method just call getEmployeeData() method.

This will execute the if condition when the subscription is complete and data is consistent.